when a hit occurs in the game, the object is pushed back, but the hit trigger is not activated?
I followed this tutorial , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rTK68omQow&t=3747s , I have quite strong differences, however if I try to hit a slime in the game, then the trigger hit does not work, and I can not remove the interface, because the animation works but then the repulsion does not work.
game object code
Animator animator;

Rigidbody2D rb;

public float knockbackDamping = 0.5f;

public float health = 3;

public float Health { get => throw new System.NotImplementedException(); set => throw new System.NotImplementedException(); }

public void Start()
{
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();


} public void TakeDamge(float damage)
{
    throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    health -= damage;
    if (health <= 0) 
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("death");
    }
    if (damage >= 0)
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("hit");
    }
}

public void OnHit(float damage, Vector2 knockback)
{
    health -= damage;
    rb.AddForce(new Vector3(knockback.x, knockback.y, 0f));

}


public void Defeated()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
{


    if (coll.tag == "sword") 
    {
        OnHit(1, Vector2.zero); 
        Debug.Log("Slime получил урон!"); 
    }
}

public void TakeDamage(float damage)
{
    throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}
void Update()
{
    
    rb.velocity *= knockbackDamping;
}

`
code of sword
`
Vector2 movementInput;
public Collider2D swordcollider;

public float swordDamage = 1f;

public float knockbackForce = 30f;

Vector2 rightAttackOffset;

public Vector3 faceright = new Vector3(0.1f, -0.1f, 0);

public Vector3 faceleft = new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.1f, 0);

void Start()
{
    swordcollider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();


    rightAttackOffset = transform.position;

    if (swordcollider == null) {

        Debug.LogWarning("Sword collider not set");
            
            }
}

public void AttackRight()
{
    print("AttackR");
    swordcollider.enabled = true;
    transform.position = rightAttackOffset;
}

public void AttackLeft()
{
    print("AttackL");
    swordcollider.enabled = true;
    transform.position = new Vector3(rightAttackOffset.x * -1, rightAttackOffset.y);
}






private void SetSwordOffset(bool isFacingRight)
{
    if (isFacingRight)
    {
        swordcollider.transform.localPosition = faceright;
    }
    else
    {
        swordcollider.transform.localPosition = faceleft;
    }

    
}
 public void IsFacingRight(bool isFacingRight)
{
    SetSwordOffset(isFacingRight);
}



     public float damage = 10;


private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    IDamagable damagable = other.GetComponent<IDamagable>();
    if (damagable != null) {

        Vector3 parentPosition = gameObject.GetComponentInParent<Transform>().position;

        Vector2 direction = (Vector2)(other.gameObject.transform.position - parentPosition).normalized;
        Vector2 knockback = direction * knockbackForce;

        damagable.OnHit(swordDamage, knockback);


        } else
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Collider cant");
    }
    }
   

`
public interface IDamagable

public float Health { get; set; }
void OnHit (float damage, Vector2 knockback );
void TakeDamage(float damage);

`

If it's being pushed then you forgot to actually make it a trigger and it acts like a normal collider ...

For OnTriggerEnter to work in Unity, I believe it is required to have a rigidbody on at least one of the GameObjects. Here is a reference to their docs describing this.
"Any Collider on a GameObject that has a Rigidbody component, or on a child of a GameObject with a Rigidbody component can create OnTrigger events."
